# Access Report Fails after Conversion to 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this very old access database which got converted to 2010 recently and for whatever reason one of the reports is no longer working. I didn't build this and the owner is not willing to upgrade completely just wants this one issue resolved. Basically I have Report1 (`rptInspContainers`) which has a Report within it (`Child131`) and also this query which needs to grab the `EquipID` from the inner report (`Child131`).

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblInspData.Findings

FROM tblInspData

WHERE (((tblInspData.EquipID)=[Reports]![rptInspContainers]![Child131]![Report]![Text104]))
```

Any reason why this would have worked in a previous version of access and not 2010?

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or simply no data coming back?

Comment: Just no data...when I run the query manually and type in the EquipID it works fine.

Comment: No exactly sure, I would try adding a trim function around the value of Text104, I suspect it has something in it that returns an non-valid EquipID.   Don't know Access well enough to suggest much else, sorry

Comment: what was the previous version of Access?

Comment: I'm told the previous version was 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The later versions are a bit more fussy about . and ! so try a dot before [Report] i.e. `[Reports]![rptInspContainers]![Child131].[Report]![Text104]`

If that doesn't work create a new Module in your database, and paste in the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function MyReportParameter() As Long

    MyReportParameter = Reports![rptInspContainers]![Child131].Report![Text104]

End Function
```

Then call the function in the query

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblInspData.Findings
FROM tblInspData
WHERE (((tblInspData.EquipID)=MyReportParameter()))
```

and try again. If you don't get an error, put a breakpoint in the function and see if you can see the value of Text104.

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't get that to work so I adjusted the main query for the report to bring back the ID I needed to avoid referencing a report in a report. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I think it needed the 'Public' keyword, now added.